# Annotated tag not working with 64-bit Windows Command Console

Tags: windows, git

> Windows 7 - 64-bit
>
> Git version: 1.7.9

I don't have any problem with lightweight tag, but when trying Annotated git tag command under windows command console (DOS), I get the error as shown below:

```
c:\tempWorkingFolder\Tobedeleted\mastertemp\btc>git tag -a test_tag -f 'test_tag'
fatal: too many params
```

Please help me with this issue.

**Note**: both lightweight and annotated tags work fine under 32-bit windows command console (DOS).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, using double quotes instead of single quotes solved it:

```
git tag -a test_tag -f "test_tag"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tag name should be the last parameter in your command. See the below syntax.

```
git tag [-a | -s | -u <keyid>] [-f] [-m <msg> | -F <file>]
        <tagname> [<commit> | <object>]
```

Your command should look like:

```
git tag -a -f -m 'Commit message' test_tag
```